# Does VS Code have an extension to replace the title bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The Atom editor has the feature to edit and replace the title bar with some options. Does VS Code have a similar extension or can it be replaced somehow?

[image: title bar]

Comment: Is `Window: Title Bar Style` -> `custom` what you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean the Window title bar (the one that generally says `{WorkspaceName}-Visual Studio Code`), then you have two options:

- Install the `title` extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nilpatel.title and use it accordingly

OR

- Create a `.vscode` folder on your workspace root and inside it create a `settings.json` file (if you haven't already all of these). There add the `window.title` setting and set to whatever you want

  ```
  {
     "window.title": "My Custom Title"
  }
  ```